# I want to run aos fade up animation only once

Tags: animation, aos.js

When you enter the page for the first time, it should be fade up, but it's fade down. This problem seems to be caused by not only the fade-up effect when scrolling down the page, but also the fade-down effect when scrolling up the page. I only set the fade-up effect to the code.
How can I make it only fade up?
The web page and code are below.

https://www.dorothycard.com/v/48dc3e5f

```
<div class="mx-4" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-once=“true”>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I inspect your page, all the animated elements have the following attribute:

```
data-aos-once=""true""
```

when that attribute should be:

```
data-aos-once="true"
```

The first sets the attribute to the string `"true"` which is quite different from the boolean `true` (which is what is expected).

I do not know how you set this attribute in your source, but you will want to look there for a fix to your issue.

Note that if you want ALL your animations in the page to only run once, you could also pass that option in the `AOS.init()` function call:

```js
AOS.init({
 // ... your other initialisation options here ...
 once: true,
});
```

and you could then remove all individual `data-aos-once` attributes.